# Is there an k8s annotation for setting the name of an auto-created LB in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

For AWS cloud, I can create a Kubernetes ingress yaml containing

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig":
      { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: <<<my-cert-arn>>>
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/shield-advanced-protection: "true"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-policy: ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/tags: environment=prod,client=templar-order,name=templar-prod-app
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
```

and the `tags` come through in the AWS console, but the load balancer name is not set.

I've [read the docs](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/guide/ingress/annotations/).  What annotation can I use to set the load balancer name, here:

[image: screenshot of AWS console for LBs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this feature is not yet supported so you can`t change the lb name using annotation.

The name is being generated [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/blob/master/internal/alb/generator/name.go#L23):

```golang
    func (gen *NameGenerator) NameLB(namespace string, ingressName string) string {
    .....
    }
```

However there is [feature request](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/issues/1483) on github which looks promising. You might want to follow that case for updates.